# SQL Server System.OutOfMemoryException + too many outcomes

Tags: sql-server, join, out-of-memory, bigdata

I'm a self-learning SQL programmer.

When I tried to join the tables (there are probably near to 100 mil outcome), a `System.OutOfMemoryException` is thrown. My main purpose is to generate the combination of values; *the other table (which stored a set of other numbers) will take these values in every rows, compared with itself and devise the buy/sell strategy. This italic part is where the outofmemory error occurs.* Thus you can imagine the dataset will be huge.

This is the code:

```
select * 
into #MyTempTable 
from
    (Select distinct Parm_H 
     from [dbo].[Parmset1]) A1
inner join 
    (Select distinct Parm_D 
     from [dbo].[Parmset1]) A2 on A1.Parm_H > A2.Parm_D
inner join
    (Select distinct Parm_A 
     from [dbo].[Parmset1]) A3 on A2.Parm_D > A3.Parm_A


select * 
from [dbo].[MatchRegression]
cross join #MyTempTable
```

My computer spec is as below

- i3-6100U
- Ram: 8 GB
- System type: 64 bit

My question is:

- While online resources said it is the RAM issue, does only add RAM without upgrading to I7 helps?
- Discussed with some experienced programmers, it is the code itself that matters as too many joins are involved- so changing RAM does not help. Any ideas that I can achieve my main objective without going through much joinings.
- Since I was using SQL Server, any other software would be specifically designed for handling huge set of data (Free of charge; more applicable use) and compatible to the current spec of my computer?

I'm willing to learn anyway.

Thanks, Vincent

Comment: SQL Server isn't a .NET application and doesn't produce `OutOfMemoryException`. What you're seeing is the inability of Management Studio to present that many rows to you in a visual grid (it is not the most efficient application). Either use "output to text", or find another way to present your results (with a dedicated client application, for example). All that said, it's still possible for your queries to make SQL Server run out of memory, but then you won't get `OutOfMemoryException`, but a SQL error and details in the log file.

Comment: Do you really need to return every row of data? I would think you could add some filters that would cut down on the amount of data being returned. If not, you could query for results in batches, say for each day in a given range, etc.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks. But this is only an interim step for my program. so if I export it into a txt file, and that has to be imported in the SQL again for further processing? there would be billions of rows and I'm wondering if that still works?

Comment: @RyanWilson, is there any way that I could run by batches and aggregate the data altogether? Or at least enquire the max. value in different query results? say....there are 100 query results each with 1,000,000 rows of data

Comment: @vincentshiusun If all you care about is the max value you should write your query to filter down to only the max value for each result. Then return that.

Comment: @RyanWilson, but the result could only be available after I ve joined them. So u're saying that I could compare the result of Table A by looping through every combinations in Table B with each entries in Table A- in devising the buy/sell decision? Then the entire process ignores display the result in Grid

Comment: @vincentshiusun You could join your table A and Table B using MAX which would do the filtering without using a loop. And then return that result set. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @RyanWilson, let me explain more on what I intended to do. Table A= predicted values of options 1, 2 and 3; Table B = set of parameters so that if predicted values in Table A larger than a particular parm, it would choose 1, and iff the result is 1, the return Odds*amount bet on 1. So you can see that Table A (for choice 1,2 and 3) has to loop through every single rows in Table B (Sets of parms) and get the profit per combination of Table B.

Comment: @RyanWilson, then my understanding- join Table A and B, for each combination determines choose 1, or 2 or 3. Each multiplies with the odds/ return by each choice. Then get the max value after the result. Therefore the max,value seems to be obtained only after all the joining and calc.

Comment: @vincentshiusun If that is what you want then yes, you can make all the calulations and joining part of a sub query which you can then query from to return the results you care about.

Comment: @RyanWilson,can you write me some examples? Brief example is fine...Many thanks

Comment: @vincentshiusun `SELECT * FROM (your subquery goes inside here, the join and the calculation, which could be another subquery)` a simple example would be `SELECT x.Name FROM (Select e.[Name], r.[Role] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS e INNER JOIN [dbo].[Roles] AS r on r.[EmployeeId] = e.[Id]) AS x`

Answer (score 0):

The out of memory exception is generated by the 32 bit SSMS client that you are using.

```
select * from [dbo].[MatchRegression] cross join #MyTempTable
```

Obviously, you are not manually going to view the data and do anything with it, so my suggestion would be to insert this into another table and run queries on it , not trying to select all data to show in the datagrid or client application. SQL Server should easily be able to handle billions of rows of data without any problem.

Though, you might need to look at the [edition comparison sheet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) to look at what edition of SQL Server would be best for your application depending on size of data, requirements etc

Comment: Apologies, is it like select * into #Temp2 from [dbo].[MatchRegression] cross join #MyTempTable. then export the result into csv/ txt?

Comment: Should be fine as long as you have the storage space

Comment: What are you going to do when you have it in CSV/ txt file

Comment: this question might be naive but allow me. indeed the #Temp2 needs further working (Filtering and multiplication or case when) in order to reach the final result. Can I directly work on that without exporting it to csv file? Cuz some other users suggested output it into txt

Comment: Yes .. that would be the right way to do it ... Exporting something you already have in a temp table would not help you in any way ... I would suggest you create some indexes on the temp table though to help with the queries if the data is in millions of rows ... It would be initially slow in index creation but would help a lot in the queries futher

Comment: Thanks...It's still running...2X mins now. no error message found at the moment. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes ... It will run until it's completed the insert ... Which in case of millions of rows , would be quite a lot ... It depends on your I/o subsystem speed